# Node.js / Edge.js - Insert JS variables into SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, edge.js

I'm currently using Node.js with Edge.js to insert hardcoded values into a SQL database:

```
var insertUser = edge.func('sql', function () {/*
    INSERT INTO dbo.Newsletter (Email, Active, DateCreated, DateUpdated, Deleted)
    VALUES ('test2@test.com','1','2014-01-01 00:00:00','2014-01-01 00:00:00','0')
*/});
```

This works correctly.

However, I'd like the values to be previously-defined JS variables, not hardcoded. So if I have defined this variable:

```
var emailAddress = document.getElementById('emailInput').value;
```

I would like to insert it in place of the hardcoded email address (problem code below):

```
var insertUser = edge.func('sql', function () {/*
    INSERT INTO dbo.Newsletter (Email, Active, DateCreated, DateUpdated, Deleted)
    VALUES ('emailAddress','1','2014-01-01 00:00:00','2014-01-01 00:00:00','0')
*/});
```

The above syntax (and various variations of) doesn't work - is it possible at all to insert JS variables in SQL with Node/Edge? Many thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use named parameters in your function like this:

```
var insertUser = edge.func('sql', function () {/*
    INSERT INTO dbo.Newsletter (Email, Active, DateCreated, DateUpdated, Deleted)
    VALUES (@emailAddress,'1','2014-01-01 00:00:00','2014-01-01 00:00:00','0')
*/});
```

Pass it an object with parameters like this:

```
var emailAddress = document.getElementById('emailInput').value;
insertUser({"emailAddress": emailAddress}, callBack)
```

Comment: Yep, that's the one - except currently I'm at the server-side only stage, so once the variables have been defined it's:

var insertUser = edge.func('sql', function () {/*
    INSERT INTO dbo.Newsletter (Email, Active, DateCreated, DateUpdated, Deleted)
    VALUES (@email,@active,@dateCreated,@dateUpdated,@deleted)
*/});

insertUser({ email: emailAddress, active: 1, dateCreated: strDateTime, dateUpdated: strDateTime, deleted: 0 }, function (){**code**});