# "Node.js / Edge.js - Insert JS variables into SQL" part 2

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, edge.js

Here's the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831936/node-js-edge-js-insert-js-variables-into-sql).

Okay, I'm using Node.js and Edge.js to insert values to an SQL database.
First attempt was a straightforward insertion of hardcoded values:

```
var insertRow = edge.func('sql', function () {/*
    INSERT INTO dbo.table (column0, column1, column2)
    VALUES (value0, value1, value2)
*/});

insertRow();
```

This hardcoded insertion works as expected, of course.
And as seen in the answer of the question before me, passing the function an object allows the SQL statement to recognize a name/value pair of the object via an @, allowing dynamic value assignment:

```
var rowObj = {
    v0: 'value0',
    v1: 'value1',
    v2: 'value2'
}

var insertRow = edge.func('sql', function () {/*
    INSERT INTO dbo.table (column0, column1, column2)
    VALUES (@v0, @v1, @v2)
*/});

insertRow(rowObj);
```

Works as expected.
What I would like to do is have the table and columns be variable as well, through properties provided by the same rowObj.
I tried:

```
var rowObj = {
    t: 'dbo.table',
    c0: 'column0',
    c1: 'column1',
    c2: 'column2',
    v0: 'value0',
    v1: 'value1',
    v2: 'value2'
}

var insertRow = edge.func('sql', function () {/*
    INSERT INTO @t (@c0, @c1, @c2)
    VALUES (@v0, @v1, @v2)
*/});

insertRow(rowObj);
```

But this doesn't work. I tried making the table dynamic on its own, and the columns on their own, and that didn't work either.

note: I don't know SQL, I don't know the limitations of Node.js/Edge.js, and I'm very new to programming in general (so if my nomenclature is inconsistent/wrong, let me know but please don't tear me apart) I was just wondering if what I'm trying to do can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you call `edge.func` as many times as you need different selection criteria. If you don't know the column names a priori, you can always construct the T-SQL string you pass to `edge.func` dynamically. With this approach you would normally loose some optimizations around precompiled SQL statements, but given how MS SQL optimizes query execution on the server the savings are minimal.

Comment: I'm mostly just curious how much of a 'master' statement I could make.  The one TSQL statement to rule them all. Turns out I'm going to need to write my statement(s) in .NET so I won't have as many constraints on syntax. Regardless, thanks! Edge.js is pretty rad.